# Finding the number of possible values of $\lfloor x \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor$ for $0 \le x \le 10.$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find the number of possible values of $f(x) = \lfloor x \lfloor x \rfloor \rfloor$ for $0 \le x \le 10$.

I tried to see if I could set up some inequality, or do some casework, but I still can't get any progress.

Comment: It seems like you have omitted some context. What is $f$, what is its codomain, what are the restrictions on $f$, etc.

Comment: sorry, will edit.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the maximum is $100$ when $x=10$ and when $x=9$ you have $f(x)=81$.  In between there, the inner floor always gives $9$.  Can you convince yourself that there is an $x$ that gives all the values $82-99$?  Then apply that to the other intervals.